# Make iPhone permanently trust computer?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, usb, charging

Is there anyway to have an iPhone remember which computers it trusts?

Everything I plug mine into any computer that I've already allowed it to trust, it asks me again, "Allow this device to access photos and videos?"

It is expected to ask once when I connect it:

> to a computer or other device for the first time, ..

and

> These computers remain trusted unless you change which computers you trust
>   [reset location and privacy] or erase your device.

None of these resetting has been done to make the iPhone forget the computer.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202778

[image]

Comment: ST215 pointed this out but without really explaining it. The Trust question pops up because your computer is trying to use the Personal Hotspot feature, not because it needs to establish a trust relationship for normal data exchange.

Comment: @ToddDabney My personal hotspot is off and it still asks every time.

Comment: @dgo what version of iOS and desktop OS are you running? I'm no longer seeing these running the latest iOS and macOS

Answer (score 3):

[ *this solution is assuming an Apple Computer* ]

Make sure your Personal Hotspot is turned off. If your personal Hotspot is turned on every time your plug the device into the Macbook it will ask for permission and make you enter your PIN password.

> “When the personal hotspot is turned on, it will ask every time you
>   connect your iPhone to a computer because it’s requesting access to
>   the hotspot network over cable.”
>
> - Dan VanWinkle
>
> Source: https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-stop-trust-this-computer-message-on-iphone-ipad/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are many criteria that cause an iPhone to see your computer as unknown...updating the OS, being logged in as a different user, whether you’re authenticated by Apple Watch, whether you’ve backed up to a different computer, iCloud login state.

If the computer doesn’t identify itself exactly the same as when you trusted it, you’ll get asked again. They try to err on the side of caution.

Comment: I'm afraid Apple mentions: *"These computers remain trusted unless you change which computers you trust or erase your device."* and *".. to a computer or other device for the first time,.. "*. https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202778#change

Comment: @ankii I frequently get the untrusted device prompt, sometimes multiple times in one day.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you connected your device into the same computer each time, you would get this message only once. Apple is only setting up a level of trust between a single computer and mobile device. (I've had iPads report this message as well.)

I'm just guessing here, but I think it's because Apple cares about your privacy. This exact message would also pop up if someone would connect your iPhone to one of those devices that are used to gather content from them, ie, law enforcement.

I don't believe you can set the iPhone to "trust" more than one device at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I just tested now. I plugged in the iPhone, entered password to trust the computer. Unplugged (turned hotspot off then back on). Plugged back in and pressed home button on iPhone, and the trust this computer dialogue appeared again

Comment: In that case, do you have anything in the network or sharing settings that list using the network from your computer?

Comment: I set it up so the computer would auto connect to the hotspot when the phone is wire connected to the computer. Other than that no special configurations that I know of.

Comment: I don't have any hotspot abilities with any of the devices that I work with. Either some setting is changing that is resetting the trust value or the iPhone is, as Apple likes to do, is making sure you are safe in connecting to this device.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps it's Apple resetting it. I could be a (security) feature. I guess I'll just keep entering the password each time. Best to be safe.